# html5 audio - Chrome is loading entire mp3 before playing a seeked position

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, audio

For some reason, Chrome is loading an entire mp3 file before playing at the currentTime set. What I want is for Chrome to begin playing from the currentTime position, and to skip downloading the rest of the mp3 file that precedes that currenttime.

Chrome 36 seeks successfully in this manner with ogg files, but not with mp3 files.

Firefox 30 seeks successfully in this manner with both ogg files and mp3 files.

In the Plnkr code below, can anyone explain Chrome downloads an mp3 from the beginning when seeking to currentTime, but properly skips to a seeked position with ogg?

Also, can this be fixed? Can I change this Plnkr code to enable downloading mp3s from a seeked position, instead of downloading from the beginning every time? Thank you

http://plnkr.co/edit/VQUgEUp7vnhyJbHRdNGP?p=info

script.py

```
$(window).load(function () {
    var i = 0;

    var PVstartButtons = document.getElementsByClassName('start-button', i);
    var PVaudioSources = [];
    var PVstartTimes = [];
    var PVendTimes = [];

    var playerWrapper = document.getElementById('player-wrapper');

    for (i = 0; i < PVstartButtons.length; ++i) {
        PVstartButtons[i].addEventListener("click", PVplayMedia(i));
        PVaudioSources[i] = PVstartButtons[i].getAttribute('audioSource');
        PVstartTimes[i] = PVstartButtons[i].getAttribute('timeBegins');
        PVendTimes[i] = PVstartButtons[i].getAttribute('timeEnds');
    }

    window.playerWrapper = playerWrapper;
    window.PVstartButtons = PVstartButtons;
    window.PVaudioSources = PVaudioSources;
    window.PVstartTimes = PVstartTimes;
    window.PVendTimes = PVendTimes;

});

function PVplayMedia(i) {
    return function () {
        if (playerWrapper.hasAttribute("haschild") === true) {
            var child = playerWrapper.children[0];
            $(child).remove();
        } else {
            playerWrapper.setAttribute("haschild", "true");
        }
        var audio = document.createElement('audio');
        audio.setAttribute('controls', '');
        audio.setAttribute('preload', 'metadata');
        playerWrapper.appendChild(audio);

        var source = document.createElement('source');
        source.setAttribute('src', PVaudioSources[i]);
        audio.appendChild(source);

        audio.load();
        audio.onloadedmetadata = function() { 
            audio.currentTime = PVstartTimes[i];
            audio.play();
        };
        audio.addEventListener('timeupdate', function() {
            if (PVendTimes[i] && audio.currentTime >= PVendTimes[i]) {
                audio.pause();
                audio.currentTime = PVstartTimes[i];
            }
        },false);

    }
}
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>

    <div id="player-wrapper">
    </div>
    <br>
    <button class="btn btn-primary start-button"
            audioSource="http://media.blubrry.com/burr/traffic.libsyn.com/billburr/MMPC_7-21-14.mp3"
            timeBegins="105"
            timeEnds="110">
        Start MMP - mp3 - 1:45 to 1:50
    </button>
    <br>
    <button class="btn btn-primary start-button"
            audioSource="http://media.blubrry.com/burr/traffic.libsyn.com/billburr/MMPC_7-21-14.mp3"
            timeBegins="3600"
            timeEnds="3605">
        Start MMP - mp3 - 1:00:00 to 1:00:05
    </button>
    <br>
    <button class="btn btn-primary start-button"
            audioSource="http://media.blubrry.com/burr/traffic.libsyn.com/billburr/MMPC_7-21-14.mp3"
            timeBegins="1800"
            timeEnds="1805">
        Start MMP - mp3 - 30:00 to 30:05
    </button>
    <br><br>
    <button class="btn btn-primary start-button"
            audioSource="http://traffic.libsyn.com/joeroganexp/p523.mp3"
            timeBegins="100"
            timeEnds="105">
        Start JRE #523 - mp3 - 1:40 to 1:45
    </button>
    <br>
    <button class="btn btn-primary start-button"
            audioSource="http://traffic.libsyn.com/joeroganexp/p523.mp3"
            timeBegins="3600"
            timeEnds="3605">
        Start JRE #523 - mp3 - 1:00:00 to 1:00:05
    </button>
    <br>
    <button class="btn btn-primary start-button"
            audioSource="http://traffic.libsyn.com/joeroganexp/p523.mp3"
            timeBegins="1800"
            timeEnds="1805">
        Start JRE #523 - mp3 - 30:00 to 30:05
    </button>
    <br><br>
    <button class="btn btn-primary start-button"
            audioSource="http://www.tuxradar.com/files/podcast/tuxradar_s06e02.ogg"
            timeBegins="200"
            timeEnds="205">
        TuxRadar Linux Podcast - ogg - 3:20 to 3:25
    </button>
    <br>
    <button class="btn btn-primary start-button"
            audioSource="http://www.tuxradar.com/files/podcast/tuxradar_s06e02.ogg"
            timeBegins="1000"
            timeEnds="1005">
        TuxRadar Linux Podcast - ogg - 16:40 to 16:45
    </button>
    <br>
    <button class="btn btn-primary start-button"
            audioSource="http://www.tuxradar.com/files/podcast/tuxradar_s06e02.ogg"
            timeBegins="1500"
            timeEnds="1505">
        TuxRadar Linux Podcast - ogg - 25:00 to 25:05
    </button>

    <br><br>
    <button class="btn btn-primary start-button"
            audioSource="http://www.linuxvoice.com/episodes/lv_s02e13.ogg"
            timeBegins="200"
            timeEnds="205">
        Linux Voice - ogg - 3:20 to 3:25
    </button>
    <br>
    <button class="btn btn-primary start-button"
            audioSource="http://www.linuxvoice.com/episodes/lv_s02e13.ogg"
            timeBegins="3600"
            timeEnds="3605">
        Linux Voice - ogg - 1:00:00 to 1:00:05
    </button>
    <br>
    <button class="btn btn-primary start-button"
            audioSource="http://www.linuxvoice.com/episodes/lv_s02e13.ogg"
            timeBegins="1000"
            timeEnds="1005">
        Linux Voice - ogg - 16:40 to 16:45
    </button>


  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: I don't entirely understand the issue you are describing. It tried it in Chrome 36 and it worked how I would have expected. If anything the MP3 loaded, seeked, and started playing more quickly than the Ogg files. Also, instead of setting the source using `var source = document.createElement('source'); source.setAttribute('src', PVaudioSources[i]);` you can actually just do `audio.setAttribute('src', PVaudioSources[i]);`. You only need to use `<source>` child elements if you want to provide more than one format (MP3, AAC, and/or Ogg) for a track.

Comment: Thanks for checking it out pseudosavant. Did you click the mp3 buttons that start at 1:00:00?

Comment: Interesting. It is definitely happening to me now. The delay is incredibly obvious. Let me think about it.

Comment: Have you had a chance to test this on Chrome on Mac or Linux? I only have Windows boxes. I'm curious if Chrome is using the system provided MP3 decoder because it is royalty encumbered but for Ogg they include their own decoder. Chrome is clearly making only 1 request for the whole file if it is an MP3 but it makes many byte-range requests if it is Ogg.

Comment: pseudosavant I tried this on Chrome on a Mac and received the same problem. seeking with oggs worked great, with mp3s it did not.

Comment: This may just have to do with the current implementation.  MP3 files are not accurately seekable on their own.  You can needle-drop and get close however.

Comment: Thanks for the info @Brad. I've never heard of needle-dropping, can you tell me more about it?

Comment: @m_downey Suppose I have a vinyl record.  If I want to hear the drum solo of the third song, unless I have marked it I have no way of knowing exactly when that drum solo starts.  However, I can see how wide the track is, I know the track is about 3:30 long, and I know the drum solo starts around the second minute.  I can estimate where to set thew needle of the turntable.  It isn't exactly, but gets me close.  An MP3 file is similar.  An HTTP client knows the full file size, and if its a constant bitrate file, we know roughly how long it is in time, and can guess at what point the desired time

Comment: +1 if i could @Brad. Great explanation. So in order to needle drop, would I need to estimate the desired byte range of an mp3? And to set the byte range, would I need to set the Request header in an XMLHttpRequest, using Range: bytes=###-###? Or is there some other way to needle drop? Sorry this is new to me. If there are any docs I should refer to to help me learn how to needle drop, I'd appreciate your input.

Comment: @m_downey Yes, you would estimate the start byte of where you think your data will be, and then run until you get a valid MPEG frame.  (All the codecs I know of will let you run junk data in until you get a valid frame... they do the stream synchronization for you.)  This isn't something that you can readily change though.  This would be up to the Chromium developers, or the developers of whatever code Chrome is using to play back MP3.  As others have said, that might be system dependent.  Browsers have done a decent job of hiding the HTML5 audio implementation from you, but its rough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of investigation I have determined this is just a bug (or unimplemented feature) in Chrome. I have checked with multiple server configurations (nginx, apache, IIS) and for some reason they support doing byte range requests for Ogg but not MP3 *or* AAC even though the server properly handles range requests (HTTP 206, `Accept-Ranges: bytes` header).

Others have solved this on Chrome by using a [Flash fallback](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10087531/1152664). Not a great solution, but probably your only option.

Comment: Thanks for sleuthing this @pseudosavant. I posted a message to Google forums and will report this as a bug.

One note, I tried implementing a Flash fallback solution using jPlayer and "solution: 'flash, html'", but alas it still loaded the full mp3 on Chrome, while Firefox and IE loaded with no problem. I guess jPlayer still uses the browser's native mp3 decoder with the flash fallback? I dunno, I'm a noob and don't know if I messed up the jPlayer or if jPlayer doesn't fix this range request on Chrome.

Comment: I would try something like [MediaElement.js](http://mediaelementjs.com/). It provides Flash and Silverlight fallbacks that mimic the HTML5 `<audio>` API.

Answer (score 0):

I notice in one answer you say you are using jPlayer - over at the [jPlayer group](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/jplayer/bpzsIlPBTAU/7j3MXDrTFwcJ) there are at least ten threads and a [jplayer bug ticket](https://github.com/happyworm/jPlayer/issues/223#issuecomment-46550769) about this issue. There's also a [Chrome bug tracker ticket](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=386073) about this.

It turns out that jPlayer and other sites like Soundcloud weren't actually sticking to the RFC 3003 spec, and when Chrome tightened up their code, this broke it. Chrome have now rolled back this change, but until that filters through, you can make the following immediate change to the jquery.jplayer.js file around line 696 so that it looks like this:

```
mp3: {
    codec: new Audio().canPlayType('audio/mpeg; codecs="mp3"') ? 'audio/mpeg; codecs="mp3"' : 'audio/mpeg',
    flashCanPlay: true,
    media: 'audio'
},
```

Please let me know if this fixes things.

Comment: Thank you for the details digitaltoast. I just attempted to implement the change to jquery.jplayer.js that you recommended, and I do not know if I messed up, but it did not fix the seeking/buffering issue.

I did however notice that after the change the jPlayer shows the full length of the mp3 file before I click play, whereas prior to your changes it would show the file growing from 0:00 until 162:01 or whatever endpoint is.

I am wondering, does this change you recommend make jPlayer default to Flash on Chrome? @pseudosavant recommended using Flash to overcome this Chrome limitation.

Comment: Also, I added some extra info to the [Chrome issue tracker](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=397365&thanks=397365&ts=1406248042). I found some mp3s that work perfect with the Chrome player. I wonder why these mp3s work perfectly in Chrome, but most do not...